# Google Ads API PHP USER_PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have a Basic Access Token for my manager account 1234567890
I also have one account under this manager account: 0987654321

I've then followed the documentation, installed libraries, generate OATH2, refresh token etc and filled the "google_ads_php.ini" fileand then:

I'm trying to run the example code in the google documentation:

```
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile('/google_ads_php.ini')
        ->build();

    $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
        ->fromFile('/google_ads_php.ini')
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();      

    $googleAdsServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient();

    $query = 'SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id';

    $stream = $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream($customerId, $query);
```

In my google_ads_php.ini, I have this:
loginCustomerId = "1234567890"

In the $customerId filed, I have this: "0987654321"

And I'm receiving this error:
USER_PERMISSION_DENIED

Also just because I've started becoming crazy I did try all 4 possible combinations:

loginCustomerId = "1234567890"
$customerId = "1234567890"

loginCustomerId = "0987654321"
$customerId = "0987654321"

loginCustomerId = "0987654321"
$customerId = "1234567890"

But I'm receiving this error in all the cases. Any help would be much appreciated